# Are there (nearly) universal symbols for SAME and DIFFERENT?

Tags: symbols

I've got two buttons the user will click to indicate whether a stimulus is the *same*  or *different*

Currently I'm using = (U+003D) and ≠ (U+2260, = with a diagonal line through it).

Is there a more universal icons/symbol for that?

Comment: Who's your audience? There are mathematical symbols you could use, but I suspect your design will need to educate people about what each symbol means (e.g. having the symbol next to the word, and having a tooltip on the symbol).

Comment: While it certainly depends on context, note that 'equals' doesn't always mean 'the same'. If you are OK with icons, off the top of my head: 2 circles same color (= same); 1 circle, 1 square, different colors (= different)

Comment: from a programmers point of view how about `==` for ***SAME*** and `!=` for ***DIFFERENT***

Comment: Actually from a programmer's point of view, **===** means *same*. Two equals signs simply tests equality of value, not identity. (Of course, some languages confuse the two concepts)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: that is very much language specific

Comment: @Linger: `!=` is language specific, though most web "languages" have it. Another well known form for different is `<>`.

Comment: I'd say no, there are no symbols more universal than those. What you are using are the mathematical symbols for equality and inequality. I would say that most people with (only) a very basic understanding of math would recognize them and interpret them correctly. All other suggestions in these comments will mainly be understood by an audience familiar with some kind of programming.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: `===` is just a shortcut for `identity(x) == identity(y)` E.g. in C `&a == &b` is used instead of `a === n`, and the benefit in saving one extra character is not worth the visual ambiguity of `===`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm convinced these are the only universal symbols. There are no other similar symbols in Unicode. I.e. any other symbol with the same meaning is so obscure that it doesn't even occur in Unicode. There is `≡` (U+2261) identical and `≢` (U+2262) not identical, but those are understood to be variants of = and ≠.